# How to create Keras ZeroTensor of specific shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am a total beginner with tensorflow.keras and I am wondering how I could create a constant zero tensor of a specific shape.

For example with this:

```
zeros = tf.keras.backend.zeros((someTensor.shape[0], someTensor.shape[1], someTensor.shape[2], channels))
concat = tf.kerasbackend.concatenate([someTensor, zeros], axis=3)
```

The operation tf.keras.backend.zeros fails with:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor
```

I guess thats because the batch size is unknown during graph building. How can I create a ZeroTensor or any other constant tensor when I don't know the batchsize at that moment? Or is there some kind of unknown(?) value that I can specify?

Comment: You can try using `tf.keras.backend.shape(someTensor)` instead. That is how i normally get "unknown" batch_size when making tensorflow subclassing models with 'tf.keras', if i recall correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange because you are using a tuple of tensors and integers. Sort of weird.

You should:

```
shape = K.shape(someTensor)
ch = K.variable([channels]) #I think K.constant also works. 
newShape = K.concatenate([shape[:3], ch])

zeros = K.zeros(newShape)
```

Now, if this doesn't work because of unknown shapes, a dirty workaround would be:

```
#if someTensor is 3D
    zeros = K.zeros_like(someTensor)
    zeros = K.stack([zeros] * channels, axis=-1) 

#if someTensor is 4D
    zeros = K.zeros_like(someTensor[:,:,:,0])
    zeros = K.stack([zeros]*channels, axis=-1)
```